# HAProxy with multiple backends without conditions

Tags: url-rewriting, haproxy

I would like to use HAProxy to forward an inbound request to two servers, an old one and a new one, depending on which one is up and running, or randomly if both of them are up.

If the request hits the new server I also need a request rewrite with a special path (hence the http-request below):

```
frontend myservice
   bind:1111
   use_backend back-a
   use_backend back-b

backend back-a
   server  back-0     hostname_old:2222 check

backend back-b
   http-request set-path /special-path/%[path]
   server  back-1     hostname_new:443 check-ssl ssl verify none
```

If the hostname_old is down I would like the request to be forwarded to hostname_new, and viceversa.

However with the configuration above only the first use_backend is used.

So if hostname_old is down I get an error.

If hostname_old is up it works.

Similarly if I swap back-a with back-b I only get a reply when hostname_new is up, otherwise I get an error.

Any ideas how I can get it to forward the request to back-a or back-b depending on which one is up and running?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like A/B testing.
We will need [nbsrv](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#7.3.2-nbsrv), [rand](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#7.3.2-rand), checking server state and probably cookies to stick to the randomly chosen backend with the help of [http-request set-var](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#4.2-http-request%20set-var) with txn (request and response) scope.
Below i describe config lines relevant to the A/B testing:
`acl cookie_backend_a req.cook(backend) a` - is there a cookie named `backend` telling us with value `a`?
`acl backend_up_a nbsrv(backend-a) gt 0` - check number of working servers in backend-a and assume that more than 0 is good enough
`acl rand_20 rand(100) ge 20` - roll 0-99 and return true if >= 20, so 80% chance to use this, tweak as desired
`http-request set-var(txn.backend) req.cook(backend)` - store request cookie for response processing
`use_backend backend-a if backend_up_a cookie_backend_a` - use backend-a if it is up and we have cookie for it
`use_backend backend-a if backend_up_a backend_up_b rand_20` - no cookie, both backends up and we rolled >=20 so go to backend-a
`use_backend backend-b if backend_up_a backend_up_b` - both backends up, but roll failed, so haproxy goes to next config line and chooses backend-b
`use_backend backend-a if backend_up_a` - no cookie, only one backend up, so go to working one
`default_backend maint` - you may want to send clients somewhere else when both backends are down
`acl cookie_backend_a var(txn.backend) a` - i put this ACL in backends, we check cookie value for our backend, but this is for `http-response`
`http-response add-header set-cookie "backend=a; path=/" unless cookie_backend_a` - add `set-cookie` header, which will bind our client to this backend if they didn't have cookie before and rolled into this backend
All put together below:

```
frontend foo
        bind *:1080
        acl cookie_backend_a req.cook(backend) a
        acl cookie_backend_b req.cook(backend) b
        acl backend_up_a nbsrv(backend-a) gt 0
        acl backend_up_b nbsrv(backend-b) gt 0
        acl rand_20 rand(100) ge 20
        http-request set-var(txn.backend) req.cook(backend)
        use_backend backend-a if backend_up_a cookie_backend_a
        use_backend backend-b if backend_up_b cookie_backend_b
        use_backend backend-a if backend_up_a backend_up_b rand_20
        use_backend backend-b if backend_up_a backend_up_b
        use_backend backend-a if backend_up_a
        use_backend backend-b if backend_up_b
        default_backend maint

backend backend-a
        acl cookie_backend_a var(txn.backend) a
        option httpchk
        http-check send meth HEAD uri / ver HTTP/1.1 hdr host localhost
        http-response add-header set-cookie "backend=a; path=/" unless cookie_backend_a
        server a 127.0.0.1:80 check

backend backend-b
        acl cookie_backend_b var(txn.backend) b
        option httpchk
        http-check send meth HEAD uri / ver HTTP/1.1 hdr host localhost
        http-response add-header set-cookie "backend=b; path=/" unless cookie_backend_b
        server b 127.0.0.1:81 check

backend maint
(...)
```

In the backend sections you can tweak request as you did in your question and whatever else you need.
In this config if the client had cookie for backend-a, but it's down, then he goes to backend-b, gets its cookie and stays there until backend-b fails or cookie expires (which i didn't set up in this config). Tweak as needed.